# d3js can i attribute x value to g balise who contains rect serie?

Tags: svg, d3.js

i try to fetch a benefit by month per year.

but i need to attribute a x value to fetch each year.

i use g tag for each series by year but i don't know if i can attribute a x value to g tag who will apply for each rect in g.serie?

[myChart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXjoS.png)

2021 are in steelblue,
2022 in orange,
2023 in red
and 2024 in "green"

```
      vis.serie = vis.g.selectAll(".serie")
        .data(vis.CumulByPeriod)
      
      vis.serie.enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "serie")
        .attr("fill", function(d) { return vis.color(d.key); })
      
      console.log(vis.serie.attr("x", (d, i) => { return vis.x0(d.key) + i * 5}))

      vis.rects = vis.serie.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) {return d.values})


      vis.rects.enter().append("rect")
        .attr("class", "enter")
        .attr("y", function(d) {return vis.y(d.cumulByMonth)})
        .attr("height", function(d) {return (vis.HEIGHT - vis.y(d.cumulByMonth))})
        .attr("x", function(d, i) {return vis.x0(d.key)})
        .attr("width", vis.x0.bandwidth)
```

thks for your help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`<g>` elements do not have an `x` attribute. Instead, you can use the [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform) attribute to [translate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform#translate) the contents of the `<g>`. Based on your code above, this would look something like this:

```js
.attr("transform", (d, i) => `translate(${vis.x0(d.key) + i * 5})`)
```

Comment: thks a lot! it's work!